# Django: value error. View didn't return HTTPResponseObject

Tags: python, django, django-views

This is the view in question:

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard')
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

And when I get to the index page, I get this:

> ValueError at /
>
> The view foobar.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It
>   returned None instead.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: You didn't actually return anything in the if clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you authenticated when viewing that page? You'd need to make sure you also return the `HttpResponseRedirect` object in that case:

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard')
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Otherwise you create a `HttpResponseRedirect` object but you don't return it so that means the code will continue and the function will return `None` (which is the default return value of all functions / methods in Python).

Comment: I am not authenticated. My intention with this view is to redirect logged-in users to /dashboard, and display a template for those who are not. Why would I need to create HttpResponseRedirect always?

Comment: @Milos: I'm only pointing out that there are cases in which your function doesn't return something and that's why you're getting that error. If the code doesn't do what you want then you'll need to change it.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Return was missing from if block.

```
def index(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard')
else:
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```